# Grandpa's Travels. Where is he headed next?

Tags: riddle, knowledge, pattern

“Here is my travel plan”, said Grandpa, pointing to the itinerary on the table in front of me.

> “On November 3rd I am going to Japan first—not Iceland.
>
> Then I go to France-not Ecuador.
>
> Then to Poland-not Oman
>
> Then of course Germany-not Fiji.

Then---, where am I going next son? Why? And not going? Why?

Comment: Any hints? I see a pattern but not sure where to go next.

Comment: November 3rd is significant @Ahmed. A number perhaps?

Comment: Do earlier Grandpa puzzles need to be referred to arrive at the answer _or_  this is an independent one of such?

Comment: Independent one

Comment: I have noticed that rot13(Nyy bs gur lrf qrfgvangvbaf pbagnva gur frdhrapr NA, naq ortva jvgu n yrggre gung vf bar yrggre nsgre gur pbeerfcbaqvat ab qrfgvangvba. Nyfb, Abirzore vf gur ryriragu zbagu, naq gur svefg qrfgvangvba ortvaf jvgu gur gragu yrggre. Ohg orlbaq gung, V unira'g sbhaq gur cnggrea bs pubbfvat gur arkg qrfgvangvba.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think that next, Grandpa will

> Go to **Cyprus** - not The **Bahamas**

Reasoning

> **Country that he visits**
>  Each of the countries that Grandpa visits - Japan, France, Poland, Germany - has at least one chemical element named after it - Nihonium, Francium (and Gallium), Polonium and Germanium.
>  Furthermore, Grandpa seems to visit these countries in order of decreasing atomic number.
>  Nh=113 (which is clued by Nov 3rd), Fr=87, Po=84, Ge=32.
>  Now, according to [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_places_used_in_the_names_of_chemical_elements), there are just two other *countries* from which the names of chemical elements are derived - Russia (Ruthenium) and Cyprus (Copper) - Americium is debatable for the U.S. but it's generally considered to be named in honour of the Americas.
>  If Grandpa is to continue the pattern of visiting countries in order of decreasing atomic number, then his next destination must be Cyprus as Ruthenium has atomic number 44 and Copper is 29. I have considered that he may also visit France again, in honour of Gallium, but it makes more sense that he would vary his destination (he's seen France already, okay).
>  **Country that he doesn't visit**
>  As others have noted, the beginning letter of the country that Grandpa doesn't visit is always one before the beginning letter of the country he does visit. So we are looking for a country beginning with **B**.
>  Furthermore, the unvisited country is always the first, in alphabetical order, among countries beginning with that same letter (i.e, Fiji in the first country in alphabetical order beginning with 'F'). For the letter 'B' this country is The Bahamas (generally listed as beginning with 'B'. The 'The' is ignored in this alphabetisation).

Comment: Wow @hexomino. You calculated the logic perfectly.